# nginx - limit request rate for URLs containing a variable

Tags: nginx

I found that [ngx_http_limit_req_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) can be used to limit the maximum number of requests per time. But in my understanding, this applies to a whole virtual location. What I want is limit the rate per arbitrary URL.

Example:
I want requests to `/api/list/1/votes` to be blocked for a specific client for 30 seconds after the client has made one request. However, he can should still be able to call `/api/list/2/votes` (but after that call, also the `/2` route should get blocked for several seconds).
My initial idea was to use a regex to define a location for every route that ends with `/votes`, but than (in the example) `/1` AND `/2` would be blocked, which is not what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can chain location blocks.

Comment: I don't think this is an option, since the number of potential routes is infinite, since the id (1 and 2 in the above example) is a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `id` in the key like this:

```
limit_req_zone $vote_limit_key zone=votes:10m rate=1r/s;

map $request_uri $vote_limit_key {
  default ""; # ignore urls not matching, these will not be rate limited
  "~^/api/list/([0-9]+)/votes$" ${binary_remote_addr}$1;
}

location ~* ^/api/list/([0-9])/votes$ {
    # apply rate limiting
    limit_req zone=votes burst=5;
}
```

The map will match the url, extract the `id` and combine it with `$binary_remote_addr` to provide a unique key per IP address and `id`. Of course you can modify the map to handle other urls too, or default to `$binary_remote_addr` to treat all other urls as one and only limit by IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the nginx config to something like this

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=votes:10m rate=1r/s;

location ~* ^/api/list/([0-9])/votes$ {
    # apply rate limiting
    limit_req zone=votes burst=5;
}
```

The `zone=votes:10m` specifies creates a shared memory zone called "votes" to store a log of IP addresses that access the rate limited URL(s). We set `rate=1r/s` to specify that only one request will be allowed to be served from this IP per second. The burst argument tells Nginx to start dropping requests if more than 5 queue up from a specific IP. The regex that I have placed `([0-9])` can be replace with any regex that matches your route.

Refer [this](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) blog post for more on limiting request rate.

Comment: Wouldn't this block ALL requests from the client, that match that regex? Referred to the above example, I think your solution would also block requests to `/api/list/2/votes`, after `/api/list/1/votes` had been called.